# Find out why process got segfault with GDB

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I debug process using GDB and suddenly I got SIGSEGV(segmentation fault)

When I look at registers and instructions, all is fine.

`subs r2,r2,r2`

How can I find out why did I get segmentation fault?

Comment: Please show your _actual_ GDB output.

Comment: @EmployedRussian that not happend right now , but that what I saw, there is not more information. So I want to know how can I get more details why seg fault is happend